# Remove bulk actions based on user role or capabilities

Tags: functions, filters, bulk

How can I remove the "bulk actions" based on user roles or capabilities.
Actually I have this code to do the job, but now I need to exclude the site admin, I need to let the administrator to access the bulk menu

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'edit-post', '__return_empty_array' );
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-' . 'upload', '__return_empty_array' );
```

How can I exclude roles or capabilities from that filter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this this way - Just add a new mu plugin or normal plugin:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/** Plugin Name: Limit Bulk actions to Editor & Admin */

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_53371_remove_bulk_actions' );
function wpse_53371_remove_bulk_actions()
{
    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_others_pages' ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', '__return_empty_array' );
        add_filter( 'bulk_actions-upload',    '__return_empty_array' );
    }
}
```

this will check if current user is Editor or admin - if not then bulk actions will be removed. For more about Roles & Capabilities [look here in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities).