# Remove Bulk Action For non admin user

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to remove bulk action for non admin user (shop manager to be specific),
so I got this code that let me to remove the bulk action for all users.

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', '__return_empty_array', 100 );
```

How can I make it working only for the shop manager role users?

I also tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53371/remove-bulk-actions-based-on-user-role-or-capabilities), but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can remove bulk actions for any user not an administrator.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_remove_bulk_actions' );
function my_remove_bulk_actions() {
if ( ! is_admin() )
   return;

if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
  add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', '__return_empty_array', 100 );

 }
}
```

If you would like to target just the shop manager you can edit the if statement

`if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )`

to

`if ( current_user_can( 'shop_manager' ) )`

Tested and working on latest version of WordPress, 5.0.3 at time of posting.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can):

> While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is
>   supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce
>   unreliable results.

It further stated:

> Passing role names to `current_user_can()` is discouraged as this is
>   not guaranteed to work correctly (see
>   [#22624](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624)).

Therefore, `current_user_can()` should not be used to check a user's role. It should be used to check if a user has a specific capability.

You may change the [Shawn w](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326621/60139) code as follows:

```
// for all the non-admin roles
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { ...

// just for the Shope Manager role
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) { ...
```